# Error transforming geometry into lat-long coordinates

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, geometry, coordinates

I'm trying to transform some geometries from the postgis database into lat long coordinates:

This is the query:

```
SELECT st_x (geometry) as lng, st_y (geometry) as lat FROM final
```

and this is the error I receive:

```
SQL error:

ERROR: Argument to X () must be a point
```

Comment: `geometry` is not a point - seems clear enough

Comment: It is not a point, it is a polygon ... and in the case of the polygon, how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a table of extracted coordinates from all vertices of the (table of) polygons, run

```
SELECT poly.<id>,
       dmp.path[1] AS ring,
       dmp.path[2] AS vtx,
       ST_X(dmp.geom) AS lon,
       ST_Y(dmp.geom) AS lat
FROM   final AS poly,
       LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(poly.geometry) AS dmp
ORDER BY
       1, 2, 3
;
```

where

- `ring [INT]` represents the (inner) ring the vertex is taken from (in order from outer to inner ring)
- `vtx [INT]` denotes the vertex sequence (in order from `ST_StartPoint` to `ST_EndPoint`of the linear component (ring as LineString))

Comment: thx. @Vincent-bré for correcting the double `ST_X`

Answer (score 6):

A polygon does not have a single X coordinate and a single Y coordinate. A polygon is an **accumulation of vertices with an X and Y coordinate**.

You can use the `ST_AsText` function to get the WKT representation of your geometry :

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geom) 
FROM polygon -- change the name of your table
-- Result example : 
-- POLYGON((-0.606871159358866 44.8533728143996,-0.607088886443168 44.8527320746944,-0.606672094596075 44.8527569577897,-0.606441925964099 44.8531177626723,-0.606441925964099 44.8531986327321,-0.606871159358866 44.8533728143996))
```

To get a single X and Y coordinate, you can use the centroid of the polygon.

```
WITH centro AS (SELECT ST_Centroid(geom) as geom FROM test_poly)
SELECT ST_X(geom) as X, ST_Y(geom) 
FROM centro
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, I'll add another solution.

Run the Postgre/PostGIS SQL script:

`SELECT ST_X(geom) as lng, ST_Y(geom) as lat FROM (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geometry)).geom FROM final) foo`

The result: all the points in the polygon in the format you want...